# Adding user input to a string array with while-loop without overwriting the current element at the index C# "Ryggsäck"

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop, console, console-application

So HI! I'm new to C# (started about 3 weeks ago) and have taken up some programming courses and have run in to a problem.

Here is the for loop that I'm using, and I understand that the if statement looks contrary from what I wanna achieve, but when 'if (ruckSack[i] != "")' I got the "assigned string".
Furthermore, with the current code, if I just "add" an empty string to the array the it's assigned and I understand that I give the array an empty sting as a value.

```
int i = container;
  while (i < 5)
  {
      if (ruckSack[i] == "")
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Assigned string");
      i++;
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Empty string");
  }
      ruckSack[i] = Console.ReadLine();
      i++;
  }
```

So I have a display elements of array, and delete elements from array.
So I know that everything works except for the storage-func.
I would have used a list, but the assignment asks for a string array.
How would one do to solve this?

Thanks in advance!!
Best regards

EDIT: If any one wants the whole source code, tell me and i'll add it!

Comment: Your title says *using for loop*, but in code you are using `while()` loop.

Comment: Why are you checking condition before user enters an input?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I haven't thought about that! I'll try that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If yout want to avoid that the user can type a input if there is already any string in the array, yout need to inclue the `Console.ReadLine()` into the `else`-Block.

Also, you will need to use another way to check if a string is assigned as `ruckSack[i] == ""` only return true if the array contains an emtpy string (`""`). You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(ruckSack[i])` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ruckSack[i])` (last one returns also true if only space on other white-spaces are in the string).

Put together:

```cs
  int i = container;
  while (i < 5)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ruckSack[i]))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Assigned string");
          i++;
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Empty string");
          ruckSack[i] = Console.ReadLine();
      }
      i++;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really promising. But it didn't quite solve the issue, because now the loop just runs and "skip" the else. I moved the Console.ReadLine() outside again and is able to store and then display it further down, but it still overwrites the current elements inside of the array as is. I really appreciate your comment, and I think that I will solve it, just not now. Best regards!